# multiprocessing read-only shared memory

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have found a few answers to this issue however I am still confused with the whole multiprocessing. I am trying to parallelize my program. To simplify it, I have 2 classes `Problem` and `SubProblem`. Class `Problem` calls the method `solve_` on 6 instances of class `SubProblem` and for now it is solved serially. I believe there is something to gain from solving these instances in parallel.

```
class Problem():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.sub_pbs = {i: SubProblem(data) for i in range(range(6)}
    def run(self):
        dic_ = self.do_some_analysis()  # does some analysis with self.data
        result = []
        for k, sp in self.sub_pbs.items():
            result.append(sp.solve_(dic_, k))
        return result
```

Class `SubProblem` is as follow:

```
class SubProblem:
     def __init__(self,data):
          self.data= self.retrieve_interesting_data(data)

     def solve_(self, dic_ k):
         solutions = []
         # do some stuff and call many other functions and store the result in solutions 
         return solutions
```

the way I tried to parallelize my code (`run` function in `Problem` class) is as follows:

```
import concurrent.futures
def run(self):
    dic_ = self.do_some_analysis()  # does some analysis with self.data
    res = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
          results = [executor.submit(sp.solve_,dic_, k) for k, sp in self.sub_pbs.items()]
          res= [f.result for f in results]
    return res
```

The real code is much more complex. Now after parallelizing it this way, it turns out that it is slower than solving it serially. I run the profiler and I found that the method acquire() of _thread.Lock objects is taking a lot of the time. I think that it could be because of accessing the data shared between subproblems/processes.

There are two types of data that subproblems need in order to run `solve_`: some data all subproblems should have access to it (kind of global data and is part of the attributes of the subproblems but also passed as argument of the `solve_` function) , and some other data that is specific to each subproblem and is part of the attributes of the subproblems and also passed as an argument to the `solve` function. However, all this data will not be modified in any subproblem/process.

now my question, how should I change my code in order that the data that need to be accessed by all subproblems/processes is not copied for each process? is there any hint on how to pass this data to the processes efficiently?

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy much data. As an example, I have an image thumbnail comparer. All the thumbnails are already loaded before multiprocessing starts, and the main thread feeds each process its work through a queue as a tuple of objects. (I use ```multiprocessing.Process```, not process pools). In wall clock elapsed time, the multiprocess version is about 6x faster than threading.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have better luck using threads (which share memory) rather than separate processes, especially if you won't be modifying the shared data.

It might be just as easy as changing 'ProcessPoolExecutor' to 'ThreadPoolExecutor'

That really depends on what your analysis within Problems and Subproblems is doing though. If it's using numpy or pandas, those release the python GIL and can benefit from threading, or if it's primarily waiting on I/O.

Comment: the `solve` function is CPU bound so I do not think threading would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

First, your current `SubProblem.solve` method only shows argument *k* (in addition to *self*); there is no argument for the `dic_` value being passed to it.

Multiprocessing carries overhead that a straight, non-multiprocessing does not have namely the cost of creating the processes and the cost of moving values from one address space to another. This cost is worth it but only if the "worker" functions being invoked, the various `sp.solve` methods in this case, are CPU-intensive enough so that what you gain by running them in parallel more than offset the aforementioned costs. So it may be that your particular methods are not a good candidate for multiprocessing.

The most efficient way to handle `dic_` is to not copy it at all, which is to say, create it in shared memory. But to be able to do that I would need to know more about the structure of that data and that structure cannot be arbitrary; there are only a rather limited number of shared-memory types supported, such as `Array` types. There are also "managed" types (see `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager` returned by calling `multiprocessing.Manager()`). But accessing these managed types can be expensive.

But you can do a couple of things to reduce the overhead. First, do not create a pool larger than what you need. You will be submitting 6 tasks but your code will be creating a pool with the default pool size based on the number of CPU cores you have. If you have 12 cores, you will be creating 6 processes that will be unused.

Let's consider the opposite issue. Let's assume you only have 4 cores and thus you will be creating a pool with 4 processes. You will be calling `submit` and passing `dic_` 6 times. If `dic_` is a small piece of data, there is really no need to optimize this. But if `dic_` is costly to move from one address space to another, it would be better to copy this data once from the main process to each process in the pool and store it as global data in each process' address space. Thus you would be saving 2 moves of this data. This would not be a great saving for this particular program, but it is an invaluable technique to have in your toolbox.

```py
import concurrent.futures
from os import cpu_count

def init_pool(dic):
    global dic_
    dic_ = dic

class Problem():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.sub_pbs = {i: SubProblem(data) for i in range(range(6))}
        
    def run(self):
        dic_ = self.do_some_analysis()  # does some analysis with self.data
        # Don't create a pool larger than what you need:
        pool_size = min(len(self.sub_pbs.items()), cpu_count())
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(dic_,)) as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(sp.solve_, k) for k, sp in self.sub_pbs.items()]
            res= [f.result() for f in results]
        return res

class SubProblem:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = self.retrieve_interesting_data(data)

    def solve_(self, k):
        # dic_ is now global data (presumably read/only)
        global dic_
        solutions = []
        # do some stuff and call many other functions and store the result in solutions 
        return solutions
```